# continuous functions defined of two close intervals

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I'm wondering about the definition of continuity and how they apply to functions with domains that are of the form $[a,b]\cup[c,d]$ where $b\neq c$.  What does it mean for the function to be continous in this domain?  How are these two disjoint set related in the sense of continuity?  Thanks!

Comment: At the level you seem to be asking the problem you should remember there are two definitions:  "$f$ is continuous at a point" and "$f$ is uniformly continuous on a set".  If you are merely asking about continuity at a point then the answer is simple:  continuity at the points of the set $[a,b] \cup [c,d]$ merely means continuity at each point that belongs to either interval.  If it is *uniform* continuity you are asking about ...well better say so.

Comment: Right now I am only concerned about the continuity at a point

Comment: Then all you really mean here is that you want $f$ to be defined for any $x$ that is in either interval $[a,b]$ or $[c,d]$ and is continuous at each such $x$.  Since, most likely, you are thinking that $a<b<c<d$ then continuity at each point here is that same as continuity at each point $a\leq x \leq b$ as well as also continuity at each point $c\leq x \leq d$.  Is that all you were thinking?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for clearing that up.  So basically there can be two entirely different functions defined on each interval.  As long as each individual one is continuous on the segment we will have continuity right?

Comment: You got it.  Also think about this problem.  Suppose that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ and $g:[b,c]\to\mathbb R$ are continuous functions.  If $f(b)=g(b)$ is it true that there is a *continuous* function $F$ on $[a,c]$ that agrees with these functions on the two intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is continuous on a domain consisting of several connected components if and only if it is continuous on each connected component separately. Also, a function on a domain which consists of several sets whose closures are all disjoint is continuous on that domain if it is continuous on each of the sets.

Neither statement is more general than the other. For instance, only the first one says something about continuity on $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ while only the second one says something about continuity on $((0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}) \cup (2,3)$.

I am not sure if these conditions are maximally general.-

Edit: actually, if you think carefully about the subspace topology, the second statement follows from the first. For instance in my example $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is a connected component of $((0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}) \cup (2,3)$ (even though it is not even connected if we think of it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$).